# How to automate Windows Mobile App using Java-Appium / Java-& any other automation tool?

Tags: selenium, windows-phone, appium

How can we automate Windows Native Mobile App, using Java-Appium / Java-& any other automation tool?

Is it possible using Appium-Java or at least using JAVA & some other plug-in?

Or else how it can be achieved using other popular test automation tools?

Please throw some light

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently appium supports only android and iOS , Windows os support is not der , you can try winium project in github 
https://github.com/2gis/Winium